# How do I fix "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" this error in a pug file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am using Pug as a templating engine for a project I am working on; using express and mongoose as middleware, Nodejs as the server and Mongodb as the database; I received an error when starting my server.

I read through some articles to try and find the answer but they were not applicable in my situation. [Link to article](https://rollbar.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-in-javascript/) I also read through the suggested answers by stackoverflow but they also failed to help me solve the error. Therefore I decided to ask a question.

I have only included one file and one error log; kindly let me know if you need me to add any more files/screenshots of code and files.

**Error log in browser**

```
TypeError: D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\views\employeesList.pug:16
    14|       

    15|       

  > 16|       if employees.length

    17|         table.table

    18|           thead.thead-dark

    19|             tr


Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at eval (eval at wrap (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:44:15)
    at template (eval at wrap (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:191:7)
    at exports.renderFile (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:454:38)
    at exports.renderFile (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:444:21)
    at exports.__express [as engine] (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:493:11)
    at View.render (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at D:\Github Repos\karibu-project\index.js:92:9
```

**The pug file code**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')    
    link(href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi' crossorigin='anonymous')
    script(src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' integrity='sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3' crossorigin='anonymous')
    title Employees List
  body    
    .container
      h5 Hello, #{username}
      h3 List of employees
      
      
      if employees.length
        table.table
          thead.thead-dark
            tr
              th(scope='col') #
              th(scope='col') Name
              th(scope='col') Field
              th(scope='col') Age
              th(scope='col') Salary
              th(scope='col') Action
          tbody
          each employee in employees
            tr
              td(scope='row') #{employee._id}
              td #{employee.name}
              td #{employee.field}
              td #{employee.age}
              td #{employee.salary} 
              td 
                  form(method="POST", action="/employeesList")
                    input(type="hidden", name="_id", value=employee._id)
                    button(type="submit") DELETE
              td 
                  a(href="/editEmployee/" + employee._id) Edit
      else  
        p There are no registered employees
```

I appreciate any hints, suggestions and guidance on how to solve this error.

Comment: Where have you defined the `employees` variable?

Comment: @Sean there is an employee model in the routers folder; do you want to have a look at it?

Comment: That's what the error message is about, so yes.

Comment: @SamsonRoyal The error message merely means that the variable `employee` is `null` or `undefined`, ie it has not been properly populated. Verify it easily by adding this line in your pug file: ` - console.log(employee);` and then took at your server console output.

Comment: @OldGeezer let me try this and provide feedback